# Responsive Pop up Window for Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, popup

It's hard to fit nicely a large table with lots of info (eg price table, size chart etc) on a product web page. But eBay has it figured out. Anyone knows how they do this **responsive pop up** ?

eBay size chart:

1. On a laptop, it opens as a popup window. It's smaller than the layer below. To return to the product page, there's the classic x button in the upper right corner. [image]
2. On mobile, it appears to be a regular page, but without the usual header or menu. Just a "Back" button at the top of the page and a table with the size info. [image]

**My question:** I'm looking for a way to achieve this nice responsive (pop-up turns into a regular page on mobile) effect for my Wordpress website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the responsive pop-up view, you should try [WP Post Popup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-post-modal/) WordPress plugin.
Maybe you get what you want in mobile view.

Comment: It's been over 2 months since trying your suggestion, I think it's the right time to report back now. I've been using the "WP Post Popup" since your reply came, it does exactly what I needed, I am very happy with it and I recommend it.